# Making an entire web application dynamic

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-applications, knockout.js

I know my way around the basics of KnockoutJS, and i can easily make a single page really dynamic... But i am to build a new web application, and i'm looking for advise on how to make making the entire webapplication dynamic where every viewModel and html-template is loaded dynamicly, with no full page requests, but the URL should still indicate what page i am on, eather with a hashtag followed by a path, or something better?

I'm a bit confused:

- Is there some framework that plays nice with knockoutJs that helps
  achive this?
- Can i achive this without worring about KnockoutJS?
- Is it just a matter of tweaking the viewModel to dynamicly load and dispose other viewModels
  and templates, in a smart way?
- What is the best practis, what do i do?

Any pointers, links or tips on this is much appreciated, thanks!

Here is an example, notice how the URL changes, and the new content animates in, how do they do it?
https://www.pokki.com/app/Little-Alchemy

Btw. I use ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you are asking for here.

1. Routing framework
2. External templates.

There's a simple plugin to help you with the latter: [Knockout.js External Template Engine](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine)

For the former, there are some routing frameworks available that play nicely with KO. You still generally need to do something with the fetching/creation/disposal of child ViewModels. The routing framework may help you with this, or it may just handle monitoring the events that would normally cause a navigation, and call functions that you supply.

I'd like to see a full drop-in routing framework that allows for more declarative definition of url → ViewModel mapping, but haven't found anything that is truly easy as yet.

The one I have started using is called [Path.js](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs), but you still have do do a fair bit of glue code.

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for a better answer, investigating now.